# How to fill a combobox with hashmap keys?

Tags: java, arraylist, combobox, hashmap

I have a HashMap, and I want to fill a dropdownlist with the keys of the HashMap. The HashMap type is: `HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>`

For example, the HashMap data is:

```
{A=[Ananas, Apple, Avocado], B=[Banana, Blueberries], C=[Cherries]}
```

So then I want a dropdown list with only once `A`, `B` and `C`.

I tried two ways, but in both cases I get multiple keys in my dropdown list. For example `A, B, C, B, C`. Can someone explain me why?

The two ways I tried:

```
    for (String key : FruitMap.keySet()) {
        Dropdown.addItem(key);
    }
```

and

```
    for (Map.Entry<String, ArrayList<String>> entry : FruitMap.entrySet()){
        String key = entry.getKey();
        Dropdown.addItem(key);

    }
```

Comment: Is there any possibility that your "duplicated keys* have spaces around them? Dou you also see the key duplicates if you just print the map?

Comment: How do you instantiate your `Dropdown`?

Comment: No, I had no duplicated keys with spaces, and when I printed the map I saw the keys only once. For example, the column name was often in the combobox, but it was only one line in the datafile. But it's solved now! Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two ways you mentioned are correct, however, I would add:

```
Dropdown.removeAllItems();
```

before the loop.

Comment: Thanks, this worked! I don't know why, because I had only 4x 'None' in the combobox, no real data. So it works, I don't know why, but it does. Thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

I did this:

```
DefaultComboBoxModel dcm = new DefaultComboBoxModel(new Vector<>(Map.keySet()));
Combo = new JComboBox(dcm);
```

and this also worked for me:

```
DefaultComboBoxModel dcm = new DefaultComboBoxModel();
dcm.addAll(Map.keySet());
ComboBox = new JComboBox(dcm);
```